# Why do some invalid MIME types trigger a "TypeError," and other invalid MIME types bypass the error and trigger an unprompted download?

Tags: express, download, content-type, mime, cloud9

I'm making a fairly simple Express app with only a few routes.  My question isn't about the app's functionality but about a strange bit of behavior of an Express route.

When I start the server and use the `/search/*` route, or any route that takes in a parameter, and I apply one of these four content-types to the response:

- `res.setHeader('content-type', 'plain/text');`
- `res.setHeader('content-type', 'plain/html');`
- `res.setHeader('content-type', 'html/plain');`
- `res.setHeader('content-type', 'html/text');`

the parameter is downloaded as a file, without any prompting. So using `search/foobar` downloads a file named "foobar" with a size of 6 bytes and an unsupported file type. Now I understand that none of these four types are actual MIME types, I should be using either `text/plain` or `text/html`, but why the download? These two MIME types behave like they should, and the following MIME types with a type but no subtype all fail like they should, they all return an error of `TypeError: invalid media type`:

- `res.setHeader('content-type', 'text');`
- `res.setHeader('content-type', 'plain');`
- `res.setHeader('content-type', 'html');`

Why do some invalid types trigger an error, and other invalid types bypass the error and trigger a download?

**What I've found out so far:**

I found in Express 4.x docs that `res.download(path [, filename])` transfers the file at path as an “attachment,” and will typically prompt the user for the download, but this download is neither prompted nor intentional.

I wasn't able to find any situation like this in the Express docs (or here on SO) where running a route caused a file to automatically download to your computer.

At first I thought the line `res.send(typeof(res));` was causing the download, but after commenting out lines one at a time and rerunning the server, I was able to figure out that only when the content-type is set to `'plain/text'` does the download happen. It doesn't matter what goes inside `res.send()`, when the content-type is plain/text, the text after `/search/` is downloaded to my machine.

Rearranging the routes reached the same result (everything worked as it should except for the download.)

The app just hangs at whatever route was reached before `/search/foo`, but the download still comes through.

**My code:**

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});


app.get('/search', function(req,res){
  res.send('search route');
});
app.get('/search/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'plain/text');
  var type = typeof(res);
  var reqParams = req.params;
  res.send(type);
});


var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log('app listening on port ' + process.env.PORT + '!');
});

module.exports = server;
```

**Other Details**

- Express version 4.15.2
- Node version 4.7.3
- using Cloud9
- am Express newbie
- my repo is [here](https://github.com/LeWood16/fcc-img-search-abs-layer.git), under the branch "so_question"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do some invalid types trigger an error...

Because a MIME-type has a format it should adhere to (documented in [RFC 2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt)), and the ones triggering the error don't match that format.

The format looks like this:

```
type "/" subtype *(";" parameter)
```

So there's a mandatory type, a mandatory slash, a mandatory subtype, and *optional* parameters prefixed by a semicolon.

However, when a MIME type matches that format, it's only syntactically valid, not necessarily semantically, which brings us to the second part of your question:

> ...and other invalid types bypass the error and trigger a download?

That follows from that is written in [RFC 2049](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2049.txt):

> *Upon encountering any unrecognized Content-Type field, an implementation must treat it as if it had a media type of "application/octet-stream" with no parameter sub-arguments. How such data are handled is up to an implementation, **but likely options for handling such unrecognized data include offering the user to write it into a file** (decoded from its mail transport format) or offering the user to name a program to which the decoded data should be passed as input.*

(emphasis mine)

Comment: There it is! I had noticed "application/octet-stream" in documentation I was reading, and thought that some sort of guesswork was being done about what type was being returned, but this was the piece I was missing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you define your routes matters a lot in express, you probably need to move your default '/' route to be after the '/search/*' route.

Comment: I've tried rearranging the routes, any combination works like it should but still causes the download so long as the setHeader line is present. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Nope sorry, why plain/text rather than 'text/html'. Also could it be 'text/plain' rather than 'plain/text'?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: It could be 'text/plain', or even 'text/html'. But those behave normally, they don't trigger the download.  Clearly it has something to do with the MIME type like you suggest. Actually I don't need to set the header at all for my project, `res.json()` covers most of what I need. I was just trying out different content-types and was curious about the download, why some return a `TypeError: invalid media type' and some just download the route parameter as a file.